# Finding the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, partial-fractions

**Problem_**

> Find the value of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}$$

It seems like I have to use the partial sum in order to get the exact value. But making it into the partial fractions was not that easy to me because of the numerator.

I tried to segregate the fraction by putting $A, B, C$ and $D$ as:
$$\frac{n^2}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}={A\over n+1}+{B\over n+2}+{C\over n+3}+{D\over n+4}$$
By multiplying both hands with $(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)$, I could get the values which are $A=1/6, B=-2, C=9/2$ and $D=-8/3$. Unfortunately, there were no significant properties among them.

I've also thought of dividing the numerator into two or more terms such as
$$n^2=n(n+1) - n$$
However, this method also did not give me any hint to solve. Are there other ways to evaluate the series looks like that? Thank you for your interest.

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $n^2=n^2-1+1=(n+1)(n-1)+1$, and note that $(n+1)$ appears in your denominator :)

Comment: Thanks sir, but is there any method to deal with $n-1$ in the numerator? Is it okay to change $n-1=(n+2) - 3$? Oh then, it just connects to the answer below! Anyway, thanks:D

Comment: ...I just saw there was an answer. Whoops, sorry! At least the problem is no more :P

Comment: Nono, it was pleasure to have a new idea. Thanks, sir:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add and subtract 1 to the numerator

it becomes $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+4-5)}{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}$

$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5}{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}$.(try evaluating this yourself)

$=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{5}{2} \times \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{24} = \boxed{\frac{5}{36}}$